# I'm getting [Your connection isn't private] after using ssl certificate from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nodes, amazon-elb

I have a web app which consists of 2 parts, front-end(hosted on host gator via https) and a back-end on AWS.
At first I got 'Mixed Content' error when I tried to connect my https front-end to my http back-end on elastic beanstalk, so I got myself an ssl certificate from ACM and applied it to my http back-end using load balancer, so now I can access back-end via the same link but with 'https' instead of 'http', but I get this error in the browser 'Your connection isn't private, NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID', and I have to proceed manually, same happens with my front-end when I connect it to the new https link, as I get this error in the console.
what should I do?

Comment: Check your browser console. Maybe it lists exactly which link is insecure.

Comment: I already know, it's the link of my backend over https

Comment: Has the ssl cert been registered for the correct domain/subdoimain?

Comment: I have registered it with the same link to the frontend, and I verified it via a confirmation message sent to the emails of the frontend domain, do I need to do anything extra?

Comment: There are no details in your question regarding the SSL certificaiton, so its difficult to comment on that. So your API is on the same domain as front-end (example.com)? not a subdomain, e.g. `api.example.com`?

Comment: no, front end is on a whole different domain than the backend

Comment: If its different domain, then how could "I have registered it with the same link to the frontend"? Can you update quesiton with the ssl setup info. Otherwise, I can only guess on what you may or may not have in your ssl certificates.

Comment: When you go to ACM to get an ssl certificate you should have a domain, I entered my frontend domain, which is not related to aws, that's what I meant, and that's the only setuf info I have for my ssl certificate, no further configuration

Comment: So if your API is on a different domain, which SSL cert it is using? It must have its own SSL certificate for its domain.

Comment: My API is on aws, using the certificate of ACM 
frontend on hostgator using ssl certificate of hostgator, that's it